# Pin a child view at top of the screen on scrolling using scroll view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-scrollview

I need to pin a view at top of the screen when it reaches the top on scrolling. When it reaches the top the view should stay there as a header and rest of the views below that should scroll as normal.
For example I have a scroll view and have 3 children A, B and C. On start scrolling up all the children will start scrolling an A will scroll into the top of the screen(normal behavior). But incase of B, when it reaches the top I need to pin B to top the screen and C should continue it scroll into top of the screen and B should stay there at top.

Answer (score 0):

With Compose you can try to use `stickyheader`

This tutorial seems to solve the same problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JN6x0UHRcA

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).